# Ошибка при получении данных из QLineEdit, если QLineEdit пустой

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit, qdoublespinbox

Есть два поля для ввода:

```
self.lineEdit1.setInputMask('9.9') 
self.lineEdit2.setInputMask('9.9')
```

По нажатию кнопки `pushButton`, в `label` должны показываться оба значения:

```
str(self.lineEdit1.text() + self.lineEdit2.text())
```

Но если у `lineEdit` значение `None`, то вылетает ошибка при нажатии кнопки.

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку, если отправляется значение `None`.

Код ошибки:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 80, 100, 18))
        self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit1.setInputMask('9.9')

        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 100, 18))
        self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit2.setInputMask('9.9')

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 310, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self))


    def write_number(self, num):
        m = [float(self.lineEdit1.text()), float(self.lineEdit2.text())]
        print(m)
        try:
            n = sum(m) / len(m)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            n = "значения не заданы"
        print(n)
        n = sum(m)/len(m)
        print(n)
        self.label.setText(str(n))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: расскажите пожалуйста, что вы хотите вычислить?

Comment: Экран, на котором оператор вводит двузначные значения, по нажатию кнопки вычисляется среднее арифметическое значение. но в зависимости от случаев количество значений может быть 7, а может быть 5 ( в примере кода только 2 значения, для уменьшения кода)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс **QDoubleSpinBox** предоставляет виджет счетчика, который принимает двойные значения.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#details

**НИКОГДА не изменяйте** код, сгенерированный `Qt Designer`. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        '''
        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 80, 100, 18))
        self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit1.setInputMask('9.9')
        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 100, 18))
        self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit2.setInputMask('9.9')
        '''
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self)  
        self.spinBox.move(60, 30)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(0)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(9)
        self.spinBox.setDecimals(1)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(0.1)
        
        self.spinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self)  
        self.spinBox_2.move(60, 60)
        self.spinBox_2.setMinimum(0)
        self.spinBox_2.setMaximum(9)
        self.spinBox_2.setDecimals(1)
        self.spinBox_2.setSingleStep(0.1)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 310, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Какая-то Label"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.resize(500, 300)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 0) 
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox_2, 2, 0)
        layout.setRowStretch(3, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.write_number)

    def write_number(self):
        n1 = self.spinBox.value()
        n2 = self.spinBox_2.value()
        self.label.setText(f'{sum([n1, n2])/2:.1f}')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> я не хотел отображать "0,0" если значение не введено. Визуально показать,что мы отправляем 5 значений, а не 7

Можно попробовать переопределить `textFromValue`

> QString QDoubleSpinBox::**textFromValue**(double value) const
>
> Эта виртуальная функция используется счетчиком всякий раз,
> когда ему нужно отобразить заданное значение.
> Реализация по умолчанию возвращает строку, содержащую значение,
> напечатанное с использованием
> `QWidget::locale().toString(value, QLatin1Char('f'), decimals())`,
> и удаляет разделитель тысяч, если не установлен `setGroupSeparatorShown()`.
> Реализации могут вернуть что угодно.
>
> Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#textFromValue

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

       
class SpaceSeparatorSpin(QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox):                         # SpaceSeparatorSpin
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimum(0)
        self.setMaximum(9)
        self.setDecimals(1)
        self.setSingleStep(0.1) 
        self.setFixedWidth(150)        
        
    def textFromValue(self, value):
        text = self.locale().toString(float(value), 'f', self.decimals())
        if not value:
            return  ' . ' 
        else: 
            return text.replace(self.locale().groupSeparator(), ' ')
        

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        self.spinBox = SpaceSeparatorSpin(self)                             # SpaceSeparatorSpin
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.spinBox_2 = SpaceSeparatorSpin(self)                           # SpaceSeparatorSpin
        self.spinBox_2.setObjectName("spinBox_2")
        self.spinBox_3 = SpaceSeparatorSpin(self)                           # SpaceSeparatorSpin
        self.spinBox_3.setObjectName("spinBox_3")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 310, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Какая-то Label"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.write_number) 
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
        self.spinBox_2.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
        self.spinBox_3.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
  
        text = '' if self.spinBox.value() else 'Нет данных, не участвует в расчете.'
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("{}".format(text))
        text = '' if self.spinBox_2.value() else 'Нет данных, не участвует в расчете.'
        self.lbl_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("{}".format(text))
        text = '' if self.spinBox_3.value() else 'Нет данных, не участвует в расчете.'
        self.lbl_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("{}".format(text))
        
        self.resize(500, 300)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox_2, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl_2, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox_3, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl_3, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 3, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.setRowStretch(4, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 10, 0, 1, 2)
        
    def write_number(self):
        n1 = self.spinBox.value()
        n2 = self.spinBox_2.value()
        n3 = self.spinBox_3.value()
        _list = [ n for n in [n1, n2, n3] if n]
        if not _list:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ', 'Заполните поля ввода!')
            return
        self.label.setText(f'Cреднее арифметическое значение: {sum(_list)/len(_list):.1f}')
        
    def valueChanged(self, double):
        text = f"Current Value  {double:.1f}" if double else 'Нет данных, не участвует в расчете.'
        if self.sender().objectName() == "spinBox":
            self.lbl.setText(text)
        elif self.sender().objectName() == "spinBox_2":
            self.lbl_2.setText(text)
        elif self.sender().objectName() == "spinBox_3":
            self.lbl_3.setText(text)            
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я не хотел отображать "0,0" если значение не введено. Визуально показать,что мы отправляем 5 значений, а не 7

Comment: @dutik я обновил свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Ник, огромное спасибо! я утром видел сообщение! Попробую теперь адаптировать ваши функции под lineEdit! Ещё раз огромнейшее спасибо!